# Unit tests in PyCharm fail unless they are run one-by-one or with a breakpoint

Tags: python

I wrote some unit tests for a set of classes, and when I run them normally in PyCharm there's always a test that fails. If I try to observe the bug directly by placing a breakpoint where it would normally fail and then inspecting the variables, I find nothing, and when I step over the problem line it has no issue. However without the breakpoint it doesn't work. Debugging the issue indirectly, I found that the test object that is created in setUp is somehow not a new object; it is the same object that gets deleted in tearDown.

I have isolated the issue by rewriting and stripping down the tests and this is the result:

```
from collections import deque
from unittest import TestCase


class Habit:
    durations = deque([], maxlen=8)

    def duration(self):
        try:
            return self.durations[0]
        except IndexError:
            return 0


class TestHabit(TestCase):
    class_ = Habit

    def setUp(self):
        self.task = self.class_()

    def test_duration(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.task.duration(), 0)
        self.task.durations.append(9)

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.task


class TestBadHabit(TestHabit):
    pass
```

When I run this code I get

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hunte_000\PycharmProjects\sandbox\so.py", line 22, in test_duration
    self.assertEqual(self.task.duration(), 0)
AssertionError: 9 != 0
```

In stripping it down I found that if I refactored `durations` to be an integer instead of a deque, it works. It also works if I remove the last two lines.

The only solution I could think of was updating Python, but that didn't work.

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This isn't related to `unittest` or PyCharm - `durations` is a class attribute, shared by all instances.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Oh, all this time I didn't know the difference between class and instance members. Thank you for answering my question.